# getArguments function inside customView not recognized

Tags: android, fragment, custom-view

I have FragmentA with constructor below :

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

    public static FragmentA newInstance(WebServiceResponse downloadedData) {

    FragmentA fragmenta = new FragmentA();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("MyClass", downloadedData);
    fragmenta.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragmenta;
}
  }
```

when i retrieve data from DB, i try to send data object to FragmentA with code below :

```
FragmentA  object;
 myObject = retriveDataFromDB(id);

  object = FragmentA.newInstance(myObject);
  this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frmContainer,object).commit();
```

FragmentA has a customView and inside customView getArguments not recognized. what should i do?

Comment: Can you add more code for `FragmentA`, otherwise there isn't much to go on.

Comment: getArguments() is a Fragment method, not a view method, so you wouldn't be able to call that function within customView